# How to use Errbit in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, errbit

I just install the [Errbit](http://errbit.github.io/errbit/) in my PC using ruby, and it's already running on my local. And I developed a web apps using Laravel 4, but I didn't know how can I send all of the errors of my web apps to the errbit.
I already installed [this](https://github.com/rigor789/airbrake-laravel) package, but I didn't know how to implement this on my web apps.
I already tried to use below script on my `../app/start/global.php` on **Applicatoin Error Handler**, but it's only show me the white page. This is my script:

```
<?php
...
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{   
    Errbit::instance()->notify($exception);
    Log::error($exception);
});
...
```

And this is how I create an error in my controller, I remove the semicolon delimeter like this:

```
<?php
class someController extends \BaseController {
    public function index(){
        return View::make('editor.index')  //Remove ';' at the end of line code
    }
}
```

If I remove the errbit instance `Errbit::instance()->notify($exception);` on `global.php`, the page will return Whoops error from laravel, but if I add errbit instance, it's only show the blank white page, and nothing happend to the errbit report.
And also I already tried to put the errbit on the method of controller like below, but I still get nothing.

```
<?php
public function index(){
    try {
        return View::make('editor.index')    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Errbit::instance()->notify($e);
    }
}
```

Please help me, and thanks before.